# Altium selecting problem with imported DXF file

Tags: altium

I've imported a DXF file on to my PCB editor in altium designer 18.
 The problem I have is Altium will not selcet my import. I've tried select All I've run my mouse over the object, some of the object seems to be selected but t he radius's are misssed out.
Ive tried putting all the imports on one mechanical layer still doesnt work.
This is driving me nuts can anyone help??

[image]

Comment: Pictures, steps taken?

Comment: Have you tried the "select all" command (Ctrl-A). does that one select the DXF elements?

Comment: If tried select all and what happens is it selects some of the import but not the arcs at each corner

Comment: I import choose dxf file then a window comes up with the mechanical layers in . I select ok and the shape appears in pcb editor. That's as far as I can go

Comment: Have you tried a different version (i.e. older version) of dxf?

Comment: This verson does work as I've got boards done in ALTIUM using this version

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have any kind of selection filter. It seems that you aren't able to select arcs. Clear all filters to make sure you can select all objects.

Anyway, once imported in Alitum, DXF files can miss some information (arcs may be converted into very small segments). It is a quite common issue.

Answer (score 0):

Under "Properties" tab, in the "Selection Filter" subsection, highlight all of the selectable objects. This usually solves similar issues for me.

Altium still has a lot to work on then it comes to user-friendly object selection.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a filter. You'll have to activate the selection for arcs and tracks.